# Link an FAB to FAB behavior class

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to link my FAB to a FAB Behavior class so the swipe action hides the FAB, The app will crash on startup, I believe the problem is with the layout_behavior element of the FAB, when I remove that line from the XML the app works fines. The log is listed below.

Here a couple of the Tutorials I've tried.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-hide-floatingactionbutton-on-scroll-down/
https://www.dev2qa.com/android-hide-floating-action-button-while-recyclerview-scroll-example/

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

}
```

There is currently nothing in the Mainactivty.

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"

    // I believe the probelm is here
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.deletefab2.MyFab"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FAB Behavior class

```
package com.example.deletefab2

class MyFab : FloatingActionButton.Behavior() {
     // this secion i
     override fun nestedScroll( ...) {
          Log.i("FAB behavior", "its working")
     }

}
```

My understanding is the FAB should link to the Behavior class through layout_behavior, seems kind of odd to me that you should call this from an Activity.

Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.deletefab2, PID: 18065
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deletefab2/com.example.deletefab2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.deletefab2:layout/activity_main: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.deletefab2.MyFab
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.deletefab2:layout/activity_main: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.deletefab2.MyFab
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.deletefab2.MyFab
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:649)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2896)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1740)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:112)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.deletefab2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.deletefab2.MyFab.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:643)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2896) 
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1740) 
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:112) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.deletefab2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the behavior class is defined in the XMXL, you must implement a constructor with context and AttributeSet to call the class linked with layout_behavior.

```
class MyFABBehaviorclass (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): FloatingActionButton.Behavior() {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not providing the proper `Constructor` for the behavior to work.

When defining `Custom Behavior` There is two important Constructor to overload:

**1. The Default Constructor:**
Called if your target view (*in your case `FloatingActionButton` or any `View`*) a Behavior attached via the `annotation` or implementing `CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior`.

**2. The 2nd Constructor with 2 Arguments:**
This is called if you attached your Behavior directly to your view via `XML`, meaning without using `annotation` or implementing the `CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior`

The annotation `@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(CustomToggleButtonBehavior::class)` is **deprecated**, instead implement `CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior` insted and return the custom `behavior`you created from `getBehavior()` method.

There is built-in `Behavior` so that you don't have to create your own, for example in your case if you want to hide the FAB when a Scrolling event happens use :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    ...
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        />
```

There is a couple more to check out, Go to [This](https://medium.com/@zoha131/coordinatorlayout-behavior-basic-fd9c10d3c6e3) post, it explains everything greatly